# How to add a button action in apple watch?

Tags: swift, button, action, watchkit, watch

I'm trying to add an action with button to change the text in a label, i created a class for my table row and this is the code, when i try to run I didn't see nothing.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class MyRowController: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: WKInterfaceButton!

    @IBAction func buttonpress() {
        label.setText("ciao")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically watchOS app users expect that the overall row is the button itself, and this way you can respond to taps of the row through the delegate callback `table(_:didSelectRowAt:)` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619575-table). If your content isn't being repeated and a [WKInterfaceGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacegroup) would suffice, you can put your `WKInterfaceButton` in the group and then its associated `@IBAction` would work.